# Prove that $T$ is not diagonizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, diagonalization

I'm having difficulties with this exercise, can anyone give me a hand?

Let $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ be a linear transformation. It's know that $(1,1,0), (1,1,1)$ are eigenvectors of $T$ and: $T(1,0,1) = (1,2,1)$, $T(2,2,1) = (1,1,-1)$
Prove that $T$ is not diagonizable.

Thanks

Comment: Well the only think I came up with is that $T(v) = \lambda v$ where $v$ is an eigenvector, but the given inputs in the details of the problem.. basically I know I need to prove somehow the geometric multiplicity is less then and not equal to the algebric multiplicity but I don't know how to conclude them from the given details :|

Comment: Try setting up the transform in its matrix form, you already have two of its columns, the third is unknown, but you can solve for it with the second part of information. You will get a contradiction from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let A be the standard matrix for T, so

$A\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2\\1&0&2\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1&1\\\lambda&2&1\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\implies A=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1&1\\\lambda&2&1\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2\\1&0&2\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$

$\implies A=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1&1\\\lambda&2&1\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&-2\\1&-1&0\\-1&1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\lambda&-\lambda&-2\lambda+1\\2\lambda+1&-\lambda-1&-2\lambda+1\\2&-2&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $A\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda+1\\-\lambda+1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, so since $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for A,

$-\lambda+1=-1\implies\lambda=2\implies A=\begin{bmatrix}4&-2&-3\\5&-3&-3\\2&-2&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $\det(A-\lambda I)=(1+\lambda)^2(2-\lambda)$, but the eigenspace for $\lambda=-1$ is only 1-dimensional since

solving $(A+I)x=0$ gives $x=\begin{bmatrix}t\\t\\t\end{bmatrix}$.  Therefore A is not diagonalizable.